# How to add a column from various csv to a new csv with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to add a specific column from different dataframes ,everyone with different column name in  to a new dataframe in a loop, I just need one 'Date GMT' to this new DF as the index , so far only the last one is added to the new dataframe

```
def compile_data():

    for df in glob.glob(pathdf+'*.csv'):
        temp = pd.read_csv(df)
        
        temp.drop(['Date GMT','Open','High','Low','Volume'],axis=1, inplace=True)
        join = pd.DataFrame()


        result = pd.concat([join,temp],join='outer', axis=1)
        print(result.head())

        result.to_csv('joined.csv')



compile_data()
```

This is the result I get

```
 Date GMT,Last csv
0,2020-08-25 00:00:00, 3
1,2020-08-25 01:00:00, 4
2,2020-08-25 02:00:00, 4
3,2020-08-25 03:00:00, 5
```

This is how it should look (csv* is the column I want to get to the new DF)

```
Date GMT,csv1,csv2,csv3,csv4,csv5
2020-08-25 01:00:00 , 10, 3.24, 40, 5, 15,
2020-08-25 02:00:00 , 12, 3.26, 44, 7, 16,
```

Answer (score 1):

You are re-initialising join and overwriting your output each time so the last iteration will be the one in your CSV.

Try appending them all to a list in your loop and doing the pd.concat and to_csv outside of your loop.